# How to view the list of history paths in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to view the list of paths in the history object? I can see that there is the length but I need to see the actual paths.

The reason for this is for debugging purpose. I have 2 views (SPA) that gets displayed via their corresponding URL. But my problem is when I go from the first page to the next page and then I wanted to go back to the first page, I need to click the browser back button 2 times before it goes back to the first page. That's the reason I wanted to see what are the paths in the history object so I can check what entries are being added because as far as I can see, the code I have to add a path to the history object is straightforward:

```
props.history.push("/classes/" + courseId);
```

That's just the code so I don't know why I need 2 clicks to go back to the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how to see the history stack, but you might be unintentionally rendering the page twice, so the history.push is working as intended. You can log in componentDidMount to see if it does, and be careful when using useEffect because that can cause that as well. If you're using react router check how the route is added in your app.js (for ex do `<Route path="/classes/:courseId" component={courseId}>` instead of `<Route path="/classes/:courseId" render={()=>courseId()}>`.